# Use Python to change timeline end to last keyframe

Tags: python, animation, timeline

I am building a tool to convert FBX files into sequence OBJ files in batches. But I need to be able to change the end of the timeline to the last frame of the selected meshes animation. It's the last part I need to finish this script up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about python API ?
Look for that and you'll find the code related to `bpy.`
I remember now that I couldn't find the docs, what you can do is play around with python console autocomplete to figure out where that is at, probably in `bpy.ops.`, whire are operator, but also maybe in `bpy.data.scene` somewhere in the timeline's settings where a variable can be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough for simple use. If you use keyframes for example in materials, you will need to add more `for` loops. At bottom of [this page](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AnimData.html) is the list, where you can find `animation_data` property.

```
import bpy
import math

last = 1

def find_last_keyframe(what):
    last = 0
    if what.animation_data is not None and what.animation_data.action is not None:
    for fcurve in what.animation_data.action.fcurves:
        for keyframe in fcurve.keyframe_points:
            last = max(last, keyframe.co[0])
    return last

last = max(last, find_last_keyframe(bpy.context.scene))
# if you want to get all objects in scene, use
# for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    last = max(last, find_last_keyframe(obj))

# use math.ceil instead of math.floor if you want to round the number up
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = math.floor(last)
```

---

update: ok, here is much simpler and cleaner solution:

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene
old_current_frame = scene.frame_current

while bpy.ops.screen.keyframe_jump(next=True) != {'CANCELLED'}:
    pass

scene.frame_end = scene.frame_current
scene.frame_current = old_current_frame
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I must be messing something up cus it just keeps moving the end of the timeline to whatever I have last = to.  IE frame 1 in the example above or whatever I change the number too.

Comment: edit that code works if the funky animation coming in from the fbx files

Comment: You don't need the innermost loop.  Keyframe_points is sorted on x, so `last = max(last, keyframe_points[-1].co[0])` is sufficient.  Also, last should start at -1 in case the animation starts at 0.  (Well, a very large negative number.)

Comment: Also note that if FBX supports multiple actions on a mesh, then you're going to need to walk `what.animation_data.nla_tracks` to find the longest NLA strip.

Comment: Actually, keyframes are not always in order, that's why I used `for` cycle instead of [-1]. For example `bpy.context.scene.animation_data.action.fcurves[0].keyframe_points.add(1)`. You can call fcurve.update() to make sure its keyframe_points are in correct order.